# run spark job when failed automatically using python script

Tags: python, pyspark

I am fresher to pyspark. I have a python script from which i call spark job which has 5 queries.

1. Now when the spark job is called and say 3rd query failed , at that time i want my spark job to close the existing spark connection and open a new spark connection and run from the failed query , like this i want the spark job to attempt twice on failed queries.
2. And i even want like if the first query is done the spark should have a logger giving us that the first query done .

How to proceed

```
  s=Config(spark connection )

  for i in range(1,4):
  try :
    print(datetime.datetime.now())+" ====> query 1")
    break
  except Excepteion as e :
   print (e)
   s.sc.stop() # close the spark connection existing 
   s=config(call new spark connection )
```

I want a better code . Like this for each query i am keeping is their a better way of doing .

Comment: Can you add some code in a code block?

Comment: What do you mean by 'When the query failed'?  If it raises an error, fails to return anything, returns some 'failed' record? etc?

Comment: Can you show us what you're working with? Sounds like maybe a try/except block? Closing the session will wipe out any values within the session, so you'll need to re-execute the entire script

Comment: @JeffUK :: Yup if any query in the middle fails i want it to retry again from that query and in the log text i want it to print the error